# t-test shows significance. What tools can help me answer how much better/worse things got?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I am analyzing if and then how much a change (called Overlay here) affects scrolling performance in a web application.
I gathered samples of frame-rates during scrolling using a script under different amounts of CPU throttling.

```
Base                        4x slow                     6x slow     
Native      Overlay         Native      Overlay         Native      Overlay 
29.28478376 33.8036851      9.678096546 9.783588462     8.160747525 6.389181987 
45.79741379 42.08519777     11.06648353 11.18818528     6.530966626 6.81918236  
47.17193825 42.58730397     13.33991174 11.26092558     9.254861184 6.980630803 
46.21401848 42.58437028     12.25613888 9.860781713     8.270770428 7.006253596 
46.59592765 43.96727025     11.89224923 10.66892597     8.167648186 7.506019994 
45.73719275 37.03965967     11.75001836 10.77861206     9.219388917 7.433513778 
47.85547646 40.3649466      14.24738702 12.05079766     8.28932676  7.230761787 
47.33250038 41.67854199     11.33568549 10.50913677     8.574772012 7.208823176 
38.04238369 41.41051523     11.59351104 11.24437161     7.439666222 7.107454256 
44.92303627 42.59730823     13.81178999 10.85663652     8.074225884 7.490913137 

mean    
43.89546715 40.81187991     12.09712718 10.82019616     8.198237374 7.117273487 
std 
5.837562361 3.086045481     1.376117801 0.6783716307    0.794948145 0.3435222626
```

I read up on and ran a t-test (two-tailed, homoscedastic) using p=0.05 to reject the null hypothesis.

```
case    t-test p value      
Base    0.1570227595                            
4x slow 0.01692231593                           
6x slow 0.000944540278
```

I can see that there is a significant difference on slower computers (the base case would also be significant if I would remove the first data points `29.28478376  33.8036851` that could be considered outliers).

What I'd like to do now is answer as best as possible *how badly does Overlay hurt scrolling performance?*

What first comes to my mind is gather many groups of samples and look at the difference between the means of those groups. I don't do statistical analyses often and this might be a primitive approach.

What types of analyses and tools can I use to answer that question?

Comment: Compute a confidence interval for the difference between groups.  That should tell you how precise your estimate of the difference is.

Comment: Thank Demitri, some resources mention that a cohen's d effect size score can be a good companion to a t-test to show the magnitude of change.

Comment: That is one way, but cohen's d is a ratio of the difference between groups to the variance of the outcome, which can be hard to grok.  The confidence interval provides a measure which is on a directly  interpretable scale; scrolling performance.

Comment: Makes sense, I will look into this. I guess that keeping track of cohen's d is still a good idea. Especially as I test more changes in the domain of scroll performance it will become more meaningful to compare agains previous values. As I understand it, the cohen's d can also be useful for things like power analysis.